# How to test if my population is orderable?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ranking

I perform repeated experiment, which takes, e.g. 1s, such that time $t \in [0,1]$. I observe variable $x$, which is an event. So for each experiment $i$, $x=1$ at some random time $t_i$, and $x=0$ the rest of the time. The underlying distribution of event times is unknown.

**Question 1:** Assume I am observing two different events $x$ and $y$. I would like test whether the two events are orderable. I define them as orderable if either $t^x > t^y$, or $t^x < t^y$ sufficiently frequently to be  unlikely to have happened by chance. I need a function $o(\vec{t}^x, \vec{t}^y) \in [0,1]$ where $o = 1$ means that they are perfectly orderable, and $o=0$ means that there is no perceived order beyond chance. I suspect that the function should also provide the confidence level. What are my options for the function $o$ and computing its confidence level?

**Question 2:** Assume I am observing 20 different events $x, y, z, u, v$, ... I would like to test how orderable is the entire set of observations. So my order function $o(t^x, t^y, t^z, ...)$ would be such that $o = 1$ implies perfect ability to sort all events into a time-ordered sequence, and $o=0$ implies no order at all above chance. The intermediate values of $o$ would imply that some part of the events are orderable to some extent, but I can't really think of precise definition, as there is a lot of flexibility. I would appreciate suggestions for new or existing metrics to evaluate orderability and associated confidence.

I apologize in advance for not using correct terminology, as knowing the precise names of the metrics I am looking for is part of the question.